# Is it possible to get all files of particular folder from google drive?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-7, google-drive-api, drupal-modules

I want to fetch all files of particular folder using google drive api.

I used **google drive sync** module in my **drupal** project, using it i can able to fetch all files and folder from google drive.but i want to display all files link from the particular folder instead of display folder directly.

I have folder id and google drive folder link.

Can anyone tell me how to display files link from the particular folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can 
Google drive provides Children API. you can check here 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list#http-request

and if you want to test it
you can test it here 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list#try-it

Hope this will help you.